# How to get HTML <video> data as a blob in JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, blob, webrtc

I am trying to get the data of the video which was loaded in my browser as a blob in JS so that i can send it over a webRTC data channel.

Are there any methods to do so without extracting the data frame by frame? And even if we extract the data frame by frame then how do we recombine it at the other end?

Comment: Firefox is having HTMLVideoElement.mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded as well as HTMLCanvasElemenet.captureStream implementations. Maybe you can't currently use these MediaStream(s) as input-source for WebRTC RTCPeerConnection API however you can use MediaRecorder API to get Blobs (intervals-based blobs or longer blob). You can send those Blobs directly using WebRTC data channels API (because Firefox is supporting Blobs sharing as well). AFAIK, chrome isn't currently supporting captureStreamUntilEnded API.

Comment: Thanks mate. Do you know how peer5 CDN does it then?  Big fan of your site :) .

Comment: Why do you want to send it via a DataChannel - why don't you use `addStream` of your peer connection?

Comment: @Robert 1. i want to speed up the download by splitting the video into multiple parts, 2. i am not making a video chat app. Its like a person is watching a video on youtube and another person who is watching the same video is downloading the same video form multiple peers rather then the main server